# Python: Plotting an integral function

Tags: python

I saw there are some similar questions around here but none of them seems to really get to my problem.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as mp
from scipy.integrate import * 

deltat = 30.0e-6
ku = 50.0e-12
pant = 0.05
csc = 200.0e-12
tausc = 150.0e-6

def int1(tp, tausc, csc, t):
    return (1/csc)*(np.exp(-tp/tausc))

def deltafisc(t):
    return quad(int1, 0, np.inf, args=(tausc, csc, t))

t = np.linspace(-2.0, 2.0, num=100)*1e-4

mp.plot(t,deltafisc(t))
mp.show()
```

The function works, but when I try to plot it report a mistake.

Comment: Please share the error in your post. Also, please fix the indentation.

Comment: The `quad` function will numerically integrate your I suppose correlation function. The result will be a tuple. You cannot plot the tuple versus your 100 data points on the x axis.

Comment: yes. exactly. your t value has 100 data points and deltafisc(t) is having just two datapoints. To have a better idea you can try mp.plot(t[:2],deltafisc(t)). this will take equal points and plot.

Comment: You should have the number of data point in x and y-axis.  In your current code, there are 100 points on the x-axis and 2 points are on the y-axis.